# Select Statement Gathering Dates

Tags: date-arithmetic, sql

I have a form where I submit a Start and End date to book of holidays, I then send the value's across to SQL, now i'm a bit stuck because what I need to do is get the dates between the start and end date.

Can anyone help me with this I just need a calculation for my select statement to transfer all the dates between and on the start and end date.

Thanks in advance to your answers/replies :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well im doing it through ASP classic and I tried doing a do while to calculate the days between but I couldn't declare the the Do while, when declaring a variable. I'm trying to store the days between the two dates in a variable

Comment: Can you show the table structure?

Comment: I've got multiple tables and the data inside is confidential i'm afraid.

Comment: Can you show the date columns at least?

Comment: How can I show you them? I don't know how to display a table on here?

Comment: I will edit my answer.

Comment: By the way you can just highlight your table and then just copy and paste it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime
DECLARE @ToDate datetime
SELECT @FromDate=FromDateCol FROM TableName
SELECT @ToDate=ToDateCol FROM TableName
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT CAST(@FromDate AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    cte   
  WHERE   DateValue + 1 < @ToDate
)

SELECT  DateValue
FROM    cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Not quite, I only have the Start and end Dates I dont have the Dates between them and I need a calculation or something to give me the dates between so I can use the dates between in my application

Comment: @ByronMcGrath: My friend, do you have a date column in your table? You are trying to select from the table where the value of datecolumn is in between the parameters(@FromDate and @ToDate), right?

Comment: I have 1 Column Called StartDate with all start date and then a column next to it called EndDate with all the end dates of how long someone wants to book off for

Answer (score 0):

That should not be to difficult to difficult to figure if you are using SQL server! Try this website it is good documentation on how to retrieve those dates that you need.

These are the select statements:
start date (PRSTDATE) and the end date (PRENDATE)

SELECT statement
docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/.../rrefsqlj41360.htm...‎

Comment: Have you got the url :)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just do a while loop,

```
While @Date <= @EndDate
Begin
    Set @Date = DATEADD(DD, 1, @Date)
    Select @Date
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the URL, all I have is the web address!  Paste it into your search engine. I Hope it helps...

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj41360.html